# Accessing TabNavigator from child mxml :-Adobe AIR

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air

This is my AIR application's UI structure::

**Tab Navigater(Main UI)**

**-->child1.mxml**
  (toggle button bar)

```
  |--element1.mxml
  |--element2.mxml
  |--element3.mxml
```

**-->child2.mxml**
   (toggle button bar)

```
  |--element1.mxml
  |--element2.mxml
  |--element3.mxml
```

**-->child3.mxml**
    (toggle button bar)

```
  |--element1.mxml
  |--element2.mxml
  |--element3.mxml
```

I want to access the parent element and change that index from child element  and child of child element..Can you help me? or advice me.
**Example:**
I want to change the tab from the elemet2.mxml in child3.mxml

Comment: you can access the parent by using the .parent property.  However, it is not the best way.  The best way would be to dispatch and listen for events.  From your example it is hard to tell exactly how your code is structured.  Can you paste some here and we can give you an idea of how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not access directly.You can access through some frameworks or eventlistener.

Answer (score 0):

For encapsulation purposes you should never access a parent.  The proper approach is to dispatch an event from the child and listen to it the parent.  In your event listener method you can perform the parent functionality you desire.